# Is there any impredicative definition or axiom which has no predicative counterpart?

Tags: logic, philosophy

I was thinking about this question for a while and after some time, I did some research on it and found some sources.

For example, in $1.3.2$ of [this(1)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/#ConVerIntSetThe) one, Myhill states that Power Set Axiom (which is impredicative) is stronger than its predicative counterpart Exponentiation Axiom and its result subset collection. There is also Separation Axiom in $1.3.1$ but both of them have a predicative counterpart although they are not stronger than the impredicative ones.

With a further research, I found [this(2)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/176d/704ffb2b2c82f1393e64d4a2e9f918df4d9d.pdf) one and got excited because of the second part **"The identity of indiscernibles, Ramsey, and the
counterexamples to the axiom of reducibility"**. Since axiom of reducibility roughly says that any propositional function can be expressed by a formally equivalent predicative truth function, I thought I could try to find a counter-example to that argument. However, I am not used to type theory and $(2)$ needs some to be understood. Therefore, I could not grasp the idea given there.

In short, can you give an impredicative definition, axiom or maybe a proof, preferably with a source, which hasn't got even weaker predicative counterpart? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about the existence of zero-sharp or the existence of measurable cardinal?Model-theoretic definition of a measurable cardinal seems definitely impredicative (as it requires full universe to define an ordinal.) However I do not know whether there is a predicate analogue of a measurable cardinal.

Comment: Your question is too vague to be well-defined. There are essentially as many 'kinds' of "predicative" as there are philosophies of mathematics. So which one are you referring to? Note that some accept the existence of a fixed model of PA, and hence PA and ACA and maybe even ATR are predicative, but Π[1,1]-CA is not. There are others who think higher-order arithmetic is predicative, but it is not clear how much higher they would accept as predicative. Even if one accepts the iterative conception of the cumulative hierarchy, one would still be stuck below $V_{ω_1}$.